# What does this line of code translate to ? and why divide by 16?

Tags: c

I have been trying to translate this code to put it in simple terms to understand but can't quite get it.

Can someone help me understand it better and why the next line would they want to divide by 16?

```
char r = (c+n1+n2)>=16 ? 
    ((c+n1+n2)-16+'0') : 
    ((c+n1+n2)>9?((c+n1+n2)+55):(c+n1+n2)+'0');
c = (c+n1+n2)/16;
```

the lines above this are a while loop to print multiple numbers and are:

```
int i=s1-1, j=s2-1, c=0, k=0;// sets up for the calculations -1
// for the s1 and s2 because you do not want null character included here

// k is the number of places we use for addition
printf("COL d d c\n");

while(i>=0 || j>=0){
    int n1 = i<0?0:num1[i]-'0';// is converting from the character representation 
    // of a number to the actual integer value of the same digit if not 0
    int n2 = j<0?0:num2[j]-'0';
    char r = (c+n1+n2)>=16 ? 
       ((c+n1+n2)-16+'0') :
       ((c+n1+n2)>9?((c+n1+n2)+55):(c+n1+n2)+'0');
    c = (c+n1+n2)/16;
    printf("%3d : %d+%d+%d = %c\n", k, n1, n2, c, r);
    i--; 
    j--;
    k++;
}
```

Comment: This code is a bit ugly, but a `/16` for an integer basically shifts out the lower 4 bits.

Comment: could you explain a bit further by shifts out the lower 4 bits ?

Comment: "shifting out the lower 4 bits" means that, for example, if your number in binary is, 11011001010, then dividing that by 16 gives you 1101100. If it's not clear, then try some examples in binary. 16 is 10000 in binary. Computers compute in binary.

Comment: There are many variables that are not known. `s1, s2, num1, num2` What is the purpose of this program?

Comment: s1 & s2 is the length of the array and subtracting 1 to ignore the void loop, while num 1 & 2 are just values in a array. the purpose of the program is to add two hexadecimal integer numbers that can have an arbitrarily large number of digits

Comment: It is not just a bit ugliy. It is a plain mess! It reminds me of the times of the good old C64, where a challenge existed about who can fabricate the most interesting program in Basic that fits into one single line. Just even more ugly would only be a program in Brainfuck :-) I think the brevity here has nothing to do with performant execution. I mean, the programmer used char values in some part of the calculation and in others he used the ASCII numbers. The only reason to do this, seems to be to make the code hard to understand. No good practice.

Comment: yes it is very confusing. I thought I was going crazy and just could not understand what was completely going on here.

Comment: Hmm it is also a real odd kind of calculation. The digits are output in hex, but it is neither a proper addidion in decimal, nor in hex. It's just a strange combination. Probably it should have been a hex addition, but to be one, the character translation of A-F into numers is missing.

Comment: is there a way that you would do the calculation better and if so could you show an example ? im trying to understand this as much as possible

Comment: It is like asking about a story showing only a sentence from a book out of context, without saying which book and what is it about. Without specifying the purpose of the program, the purpose of this calculation, what does it do, when and what for, we cannot "know" why would "they want to divide by 16".

Comment: @nath: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, the function above was intended to add two hex strings. I believe this, because the line in question encodes hex characters and the overflow, that occurs when adding two digits is treated in a way, that makes only sense if the digits are treated as 4 bit digts (hex digits). E.g. because of the division by 16.

If I am right, the hex decoding contains a bug, while the hex encoding for outputting the result seems almost correct. Almost, because if I got it right, the original version will not be able to calculate string additions like "00F" + "00F" correctly (see last output below).
It seems, as if even the original author was overwhelmed by his code.

Here is a version, that should do, what the original author intended to do:

```
void string_add(char num1[], char num2[], int s1, int s2) {
    int i=s1-1, j=s2-1, c=0, k=0;// sets up for the calculations -1 for the s1 and s2 because you do not want null character included here
    int z=0;
    // k is the number of places we use for addition
    printf("COL d d c\n");

    while(i>=0 || j>=0){
        /*
         * the following lines represent the expressions
         *     int n1 = i<0?0:num1[i]-'0';// is converting from the character representation of a number to the actual integer value of the same digit if not 0
         *     int n2 = j<0?0:num2[j]-'0';
         * I added the conversion of hex digits in the range A-F
         */

        int n1, n2= 0;
        char r;

        if(i>=0) {
            n1= num1[i];
            if(n1>='A') {
                n1-= 'A'-10;
            } else {
                n1-= +'0';
            }
        }

        if(j>=0) {
            n2= num2[j];
            if(n2>='A') {
                n2-= 'A'-10;
            } else {
                n2-= '0';
            }
        }


        /*
         * the following code is, what the line
         *     char r = (c+n1+n2)>=16?((c+n1+n2)-16+'0'):((c+n1+n2)>9?((c+n1+n2)+55):(c+n1+n2)+'0');
         * originally did (I also do a partial calculation of the line
         *     c = (c+n1+n2)/16; 
         * to avoid repeating the term
         */
        c= c+n1+n2;
        r= c&15;        // only take the lower 4 bits (ignore overflow bits)
        z|= r << (4*k);
                        // construct the binary representation (shift the 4 bits into position and use bitwise or to add them to z)
        if(r>9) {
            r+= 'A'-10; // produces chars in range A-F = (ascii('G')-16+c
        } else {
            r+= '0';    // produces chars in range 0-9 if no overflow occurs
        }

        /*
         * now just do the /16 part of 
         *     c = (c+n1+n2)/16;
         */
        c/= 16;

        printf("%3d : %d+%d+%d = %c\n", k, n1, n2, c, r);
        i--; 
        j--;
        k++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", z);
}


void main(void) {
    char s1[]= "0100";
    char s2[]= "0B01";

    string_add(s1, s2, 4, 4);
}
```

Tests (first output is from the version above, second from the original version):
"0005"+"0005"=

```
COL d d c
  0 : 5+5+0 = A
  1 : 0+0+0 = 0
  2 : 0+0+0 = 0
  3 : 0+0+0 = 0
10
COL d d c
  0 : 5+5+0 = A
  1 : 0+0+0 = 0
  2 : 0+0+0 = 0
  3 : 0+0+0 = 0
```

"9989"+"0987"=

```
COL d d c
  0 : 9+7+1 = 0
  1 : 8+8+1 = 1
  2 : 9+9+1 = 3
  3 : 9+0+0 = A
41744
COL d d c
  0 : 9+7+1 = 0
  1 : 8+8+1 = 1
  2 : 9+9+1 = 3
  3 : 9+0+0 = A
```

"000F"+"000F"=

```
COL d d c
  0 : 15+15+1 = E
  1 : 0+0+0 = 1
  2 : 0+0+0 = 0
  3 : 0+0+0 = 0
30
COL d d c
  0 : 22+22+2 = L
  1 : 0+0+0 = 2
  2 : 0+0+0 = 0
  3 : 0+0+0 = 0
```

The last output seems suspicuous. Was this really intended?

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to perform the addition of 2 numbers stored as hexadecimal encoded strings. It is obfuscated in silly ways. Here is how to improve readability:

- white space should be used wisely to make the logic more obvious: typically insert a space character on both sides of binary operators, between keywords and the corresponding `(` and before the `{` opening a block.
- the magic constant `55` should be replaced with `'A' - 10`, making it more evident that the code performs a conversion from a numeric value to a hexadecimal digit character.
- intermediary values should be computed and stored into aptly named local variables.
- comments can be used for non obvious steps.

The code seems incorrect:

- `c > 0` should be tested too to account for possible overflow on the most significant digit.
- conversion from hex should be performed when reading digits from the `num1` and `num2` strings, converting digits `A` through `F` to the values 10 to 15.
- the resulting digit would be incorrect if `c + n1 + n2 >= 26`

Here is an attempt at fixing the code:

```c
// s1 is the length of hex encoded string num1
// s2 is the length of hex encoded string num2
int carry = 0;  
int i = s1, j = s2, k = 0;

// k is the number of places we use for addition
printf("COL d d c\n");

while (i > 0 || j > 0 || carry > 0) {
    // get the digit values from num1 and num2
    char c1 = i == 0 ? '0' : num1[--i];
    char c2 = j == 0 ? '0' : num2[--j];
    int d1 = c1 <= '9' ? c1 - '0' : c1 - 'A' + 10;
    int d2 = c2 <= '9' ? c2 - '0' : c2 - 'A' + 10;
    int digit = carry + d1 + d2;
    carry = digit >> 4;
    digit %= 15;
    char r = digit > 9 ? (digit - 10 + 'A') : (digit + '0');
    printf("%3d : %d+%d+%d = %c\n", k, d1, d2, carry, r);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: @jottbe: it seems we wrote our answers in parallel... It took me more than 3 minutes to write mine and you beat me by 3 minutes at hitting the Submit button. I'll upvote yours but you should fix the overflow issue: `F + F` should yield `1E`, not `E`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I already fixed the overflow and the hex conversion yesterday. The original code was a real mess.

Comment: @jottbe: I'm afraid you do not handle `F + F` to produce `1E`. The main loop should test `while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c > 0)`